# Sci-kit Learn Interdependent Classifiers

Tags: python, model, scikit-learn

I was wondering if anyone could provide some general guidance on this topic.

I have a multi-class classification problem with many classes (like 400) but the classes are broken up into different columns (3 3 columns to be exact). They are also taxonomy based (2 depends on 1, 3 depends on 2). I'm trying to sort out the best way to handle stacking 3 models on top of each other to classify a record based on a document term matrix derived from a single text column (about 30k features).

So the idea is to have classifier 1 classify the level 1 category and feed that same DTM to classifier 2 but only have level 2 categories available which are subsets of the level 1 category that classifier 1 chose and so on. This way there won't be any illogical predictions from level to level.

Do you know if sci-kit learn has a good way to perform this kind of interdependent modeling? If not, what's the best way to do this in Pandas? I suppose I could filter the prediction lists past level 1 based on the previous predicted value and then take the argmax, but not sure if this will scale.

Comment: You have 30k features? Are you sure? If it was me, I would start simple and try to correctly classify level 1 before jumping into levels 2 and 3. Once happy with that, I would split my data into subsets for building level 2 classifiers, then 3, then I would run a validation set down all three levels. Alternatively, try running an ensemble method like random forest on your level 3 classes (using 1 and 2 classes as features), so see what you are up against.

Comment: Yep, the TF-IDF matrix is pretty wide. Level 1 classifies well for the problem at hand already via simple naive bayes. Splitting the data won't do any good I believe since the same data needs to classified across all 3 levels using the same features at each level. 

How would a validation model work? Couldn't I use the level 1 classes as features for level 2 as well? I thought about using the predicted class from a previous level as a feature in levels past 1 but I'm not sure if that would be enough to pull every line to a valid 1-3 path.